# Open Web link programmatically in IE - non-Metro mode

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

Is there a way to open a link in IE (non-metro mode) from my metro app programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

For metro applications users are in control of the applications that launch for uri and files.

To browse to a webpage (JavaScript but the C# is similar):

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://www.microsoft.com");
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).then(function () { });
```

To launch other apps you should look at the [Windows.System.Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx) class.